# how to change class name by pure javascript using cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookies

My Project example is [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xgmx11dt/1/). I don't understand about cookies.Plz explain. I don't want to change current choose class after page loaded. How to do.? Plz suggest.

**HTML**

```
<a  onclick="changeClass(2)" href="javascript:">Red</a>
<a onclick="changeClass(1)" href="javascript:">Green</a>
<div class="red">Testing Text1</div>
<div class="red">Testing Text2</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
    color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.green {
    color: green;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would better use `localStorage` for this functionality, it's simpler then cookies. For example:

```
function changeClass(value) {

    var newColor = value == 2 ? 'red' : 'green';
    localStorage.color = value;

    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.red, .green');
    var i = elems.length;

    while (i--) {
        var item = elems[i];
        removeClass(item, 'red');
        removeClass(item, 'green'); // or removeClass(item, 'red|green');
        addClass(item, newColor);
    };
    return false;
};
```

then to set correct class on page load you can call `changeClass` again with the color value saved in localStorage:

```
window.onload = function() {
    changeClass(localStorage.color || 2);
};
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xgmx11dt/4/

Comment: Thanks you for answer.I want to this answer but i don't want to colors class. How to solve using 'red' or 'green' class only in this problem.Plz Excuse me.I don't know that.

Comment: I can't solve this problem in my project.
My Project is here http://jsfiddle.net/a8m3gdzd/.   I using this plugin for change font and class name. https://wordpress.org/plugins/unicode-zawgyi-combobox/

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is building a stateful application. Now with current web technologies there are multiple ways of accomplishing this.

- Cookies (though this is the worst thing, but would technically work). There are easy to use libs (e.g. this jQuery Plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme).
- Use a server side technology to store the state of the app. This could be anything from PHP, Node.js, Ruby. You basically query the server for the state. Obviously for simple stuff like your example not really worth it.
- Use modern HTML5 APIs, the Session Storage or the Local Storage (http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) which would probably be a good fit for your szenario.

What you then have to do is, something like the following (based on jquery) using localStorage

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    changeClass(localStorage.getItem("state"));
})
```

In your changeClass function you would need to set the locaStorage.

Hope this helps